# Бот с музыкой python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, ffmpeg

Я не совсем опытный я в питоне (или в пайтоне)
и когда я пытался создать команду для бота которая включает музыку в голосовой чат вышла ошибка

Вот сам код

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx, arg):
    global vc

    try:
        voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
    except:
        print('Уже подключен или не удалось подключиться')

    if vc.is_playing():
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, музыка уже проигрывается.')

    else:
        with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(arg, download=False)

        URL = info['formats'][0]['url']

        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe", source = URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
                
        while vc.is_playing():
            await sleep(1)
        if not vc.is_paused():
            await vc.disconnect()

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\Script\\ffmpeg.exe", source = URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

А вот ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Script\bot\botyara.py", line 207, in play
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe", source = URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 225, in __init__
    super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 138, in __init__
    self._process = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 147, in _spawn_process
    raise ClientException(executable + ' was not found.') from None
discord.errors.ClientException: ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe was not found.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe was not found.
```

Comment: Ну так у вас собственно существует каталог `ffmpeg` с файлом `ffmpeg.exe` внутри?

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: @lalek после таких вопросов хочется задать встречные — А вы вообще разбирались как этот код работает? Зачем нужна ffmpeg.exe и что это вообще такое? Что такое `voice`, а что такое `vc` в вашем коде? Вернитесь туда, где вы нашли этот код и попробуйте разобраться в том, как он работает. А далее ответ придет сам собой.